# Joining two lists in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, join

Suppose I have two Lists of locations. First has all available locations:

```
List<Location> locations = new List<Location> {
   new Location { id = 1, address = "1 Main St.", selected = false },
   ...
}
```

and another is a List or Array of *my* locations:

```
List<int> myLocations = new List<int> { 1, 5, 8 };
```

(IDs are unpredictable, but my locations are guaranteed to be a subset of all locations).

I want to outer join two lists and get a result with `selected = true` for the locations `where locations.id eq myLocation`s.

If I use Join() or Zip() then I get *inner join*, in other words, I lose elements that do not exist in myLocations, and if I use the following -

```
var result = from loc in locations
    join my in myLocations
       on loc.id equals my into myloc
    from m in myloc.DefaultIfEmpty()
       select new Location {
          id = loc.id, address = loc.address, selected = true
       };
```

then **all** locations are marked as selected; not to mention that it looks excessively complex.
Is there a way to do what I want without looping through list elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what you state

> my locations are guaranteed to be a subset of all locations

you could implement `LEFT JOIN` instead of `OUTER JOIN`.

Try following

```
  locations.Select(l => new Location
  {
    id = l.id,
    adress = l.adress,
    selected = myLocations.Any(ml => ml == l.id)
  })
```

Comment: All answers are terrific and can be implemented. In fact, I am embarrassed that I missed Any() option in the first place. I like this one best because I can implement it "upstream" - that is, when I am getting the data from the database. Kamarjoba, Genatsvali :)

Comment: @Felix Glad if helped Felix. Pleasent that you know Georgian ^^. Gmertma gagimarjos :)

Answer (score 2):

Because you need to set the `selected` property for each `location` that are already in memory then you can just use the `ForEach` extension method like code below :

```
locations.ForEach(location => location.selected = myLocations
    .Any(id => id == location.id)
);
```

With this code, you are not creating a new instances of `Location` in memory like it will be by using projection (`select new Location`). The same instance into your `locations` are used.

Comment: You are correct, thank you! The reality, though, is that I can apply @tchlidze answer to build the list in the first place. That is, I won't have a list with all "selected" members false to apply ForEach in the first place...

Answer (score 1):

You are so close.

In the last query you actually implemented so called *left outer join*, but the more appropriate for this scenario would be [group join](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311040.aspx).

Since the *left outer join* in LINQ is actually implemented via *group join*, all you need is to remove the line

```
from m in myloc.DefaultIfEmpty()
```

and use `selected = myloc.Any()` like this

```
var result = from loc in locations
    join my in myLocations
       on loc.id equals my into myloc
    select new Location {
          id = loc.id, address = loc.address, selected = myloc.Any()
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

CodeNotFound's answer is efficient if it's OK to modify the original Location objects.

If you require something that will act purely as a query with no side effects (which is often more in the spirit of Linq), then the following will work. 
This is similar to tchelidze's answer, but avoids creating new instances of all the objects that don't match:

```
locations.Select(l => myLocations.Any(i => i == l.id) ? 
    new Location {id = l.id, address = l.address, selected = true } : l);
```

or using query syntax:

```
from location in locations
select myLocations.Any(i => i == location.id) 
    ? new Location { 
         id = location.id, 
         address = location.address, 
         selected = true }
    : location;
```